# C -FILE I/O Segmentation fault core dumped?

Tags: c, linux

First, please explain me what is segmentation fault (core dumped). I am creating a program in Linux which will create a file in system directory. I guess linux is causing this problem.  here is the code. The code is so simple. Don't mind for it but without knowing how to create simple file I cant create complex programs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/samrat.txt", "r+");
    fprintf(fp, "this is a demo text");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Thank you for your time and consideration. Dont forgot to explain what is segmentation fault and also solution to my this program. I also tried with `int main()` only.

Comment: check return value of fopen.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I am sorry it does not helo

Comment: It would be unusual to find a `.txt` file in the root directory.

Comment: Are you sure? Also the "r+" mode does not create the file when it does not exist, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes it helps, show us the result of `perror("fopen");` after `fopen()`

Comment: @EOF then where can i mind. I dont know linux directory well. Show me one example please

Comment: @SamratLuitel: remove the `/` in the path.

Comment: @Eof I have already tried that does not work. Anyway Thanks for paying attention

Comment: /"samrat.txt" implies that samrat.txt is located in your root directory. To open a file which is in the same directory as your executable, use "samrat.txt". If the file is located somewhere else, you need to use the full path to the file.

Comment: FYI : `"r+"` The file must exist.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, segmentation fault, core dumped error appears on Linux when you didn't allocate space for something (at least, in my case), and you are trying to use a pointer which has a null value. In this case I think it's because your fopen returns null.
Second of all, r+ is firstly for read, not for write. So if you haven't created the file yet, you have nothing to read from. Use w or w+, this way it will create your file first.
And last but not least, try not to use '/' in your filename.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `fp = fopen("/samrat.txt", "r+");` with `fp = fopen("samrat.txt", "w+");`.

check out this link for more file [opening modes in c](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm)